# moving rows as well as index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I do

```
df = df.apply(np.roll, shift=-1) --> this moves everything by one row. 
                                     first row gets to last row.
```

This is perfect however it does not shift the index along with rows.

is there a way to shift indexes as well?

Comment: df.index=np.roll(df.index)

Comment: really simple way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this yourself with `.iloc`:

```
import numpy as np

shift = 1
l = len(df)
df.iloc[np.r_[(l-shift)%l:l, 0:(l-shift)%l]]

#   0  1  2
#d  3  4  5
#a  8  8  1
#a  4  8  5
#b  9  9  3
#c  5  1  7

shift = -2

#   0  1  2
#b  9  9  3
#c  5  1  7
#d  3  4  5
#a  8  8  1
#a  4  8  5
```

Or reset the index, then set it back:

```
df.reset_index().apply(np.roll, shift=1).set_index('index')

#       0  1  2
#index         
#d      3  4  5
#a      8  8  1
#a      4  8  5
#b      9  9  3
#c      5  1  7
```

---

#### Sample Data:

```
   0  1  2
a  8  8  1
a  4  8  5
b  9  9  3
c  5  1  7
d  3  4  5
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben whoops, meant to be `.iloc`